# PostgreSQL - multiple aggregate queries from the same function call

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a function that returns a `setof` from a table:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_assoc_addrs_from_bbl(_bbl text)
RETURNS SETOF wow_bldgs AS $$
  SELECT bldgs.* FROM wow_bldgs AS bldgs
  ...
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;
```

Here's a sample of what the table would return:

[image]

Now I'm writing an "aggregate" function that will return only one row that with various (aggregated) data points about the table that this function returns. Here is my current working (& naive) example:

```sql
SELECT 
  count(distinct registrationid) as bldgs,
  sum(unitsres) as units,
  round(avg(yearbuilt), 1) as age,
  (SELECT first(corpname) FROM (
    SELECT unnest(corpnames) as corpname
    FROM get_assoc_addrs_from_bbl('3012380016')
    GROUP BY corpname ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1
  ) corps) as topcorp,
  (SELECT first(businessaddr) FROM (
    SELECT unnest(businessaddrs) as businessaddr
    FROM get_assoc_addrs_from_bbl('3012380016')
    GROUP BY businessaddr ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1
  ) rbas) as topbusinessaddr
FROM get_assoc_addrs_from_bbl('3012380016') assocbldgs
```

As you can see, for the two "subqueries" that require a custom grouping/ordering method, I need to repeat the call to `get_assoc_addrs_from_bbl()`. Ideally, I'm looking for a structure that would avoid the repeated calls as the function requires a lot of processing and I want the capacity for an arbitrary number of subqueries. I've looked into CTEs and window expressions and the like but no luck.

Any tips? Thank you!

Comment: Why not have a table containing all the information that `get_assoc_addrs_from_bbl` exposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create simple [aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createaggregate.html):

```
create aggregate array_agg2(anyarray) (
  sfunc=array_cat,
  stype=anyarray);
```

It aggregates array values into one single-dim array. Example:

```
# with t(x) as (values(array[1,2]),(array[2,3,4])) select array_agg2(x) from t;
┌─────────────┐
│ array_agg2  │
╞═════════════╡
│ {1,2,2,3,4} │
└─────────────┘
```

After that your query could be rewritten as

```
SELECT 
  count(distinct registrationid) as bldgs,
  sum(unitsres) as units,
  round(avg(yearbuilt), 1) as age,
  (SELECT first(corpname) FROM (
    SELECT * FROM unnest(array_agg2(corpnames)) as corpname
    GROUP BY corpname ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1
  ) corps) as topcorp,
  (SELECT first(businessaddr) FROM (
    SELECT * FROM unnest(array_agg2(businessaddrs)) as businessaddr
    GROUP BY businessaddr ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1
  ) rbas) as topbusinessaddr
FROM get_assoc_addrs_from_bbl('3012380016') assocbldgs
```

(surely if I understand your goal correctly)

Comment: This works! I had a separate field that dealt with json arrays which took some more work (via a LATERAL subquery). Thanks!